# Set property of yaxis(1) and yaxis(2) using set in an arrayfun call

Tags: matlab, object, properties, figure, array-formulas

I am working on changing the values of the Y-axes of a 2-axis plot. I have been able to set the limits by using the following, for an array of axes (`ax`):

```
ax(1).YAxis(1).Limits = [lowLim upLim];
```

Currently this is done in a loop as follows:

```
for i = 1:length(ax)
    ax(i).YAxis(1).Limits = [lowLim upLim];
end
```

The problem is I want to be able to write this as an `arrayfun` and this syntax is not allowable:

```
arrayfun(@(x) x.YAxis(1).Limits = [0 y1max], ax, 'uni', 0);
```

I think it should work if I can use something to the effect of

```
arrayfun(@(x) set(???, ,[lowLim, upLim]), ax, 'uni', 0);
```

I'm not sure, however, to access the Yaxis.Limits property using `set` in this sort of scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a specific reason to use either `YAxis.Limits` or [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), [`set`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) works just fine:

```
ax(1) = subplot(1, 2, 1);
ax(2) = subplot(1, 2, 2);
set(ax, 'YLim', [lowLim upLim])
```

Performs as expected.

`arrayfun` is essentially a loop internally, and is generally less performant than the explicit loop.